# Bootstrap.js Carousel load specific item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a [Bootstrap.js](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/) Carousel based on [this tutorial](http://webdesigntutsplus.s3.amazonaws.com/tuts/342_bootstrap_carousel/Carousel-Files-COMPLETE/index.html#) , it has 4 view item , each one looks like that  -

```
<div class="item active"><!-- class of active since it's the first item -->
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <p>Caption text1 here</p>
          </div>
</div>
```

**Demo here -  http://jsfiddle.net/urielz/yu4qE/3/**

it also has right and left buttons which slide the content on the menu according the the items order  .

**So my question is  -**

Which command (probably any jQuery selector) would cause to load a specific "item" to the menu  ?

For example ,  something like  - `$('.carousel')[3].showOnMenu(...)` to load the 4nd item on the menu .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `.carousel(number)`method in carousel

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.carousel').carousel({
          interval: 7000
        });
        $('.carousel').carousel(2);// use this here it index 0 base 
      });
```

**[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yu4qE/4/)**

reference http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel